# C# create 3x3 2d map with labels

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to create 3 rows with 3 colums with labels (or similar) to create a 2d "map" with data to manipulate in an easy way?

just placing 9 labels is easy but I want each labels to be accessed with the same array.

How it looks like in the form:

label1 label2 label3
label4 label5 label6
label7 label8 label9

If i need to change the property of label5 I would like to access it something like this:
labelarray[1][1].Text = "Test";
(labelarray[row][column].Property )

How do I do this?

Or could this be achieved in another way?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Data
{
    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Data[,] map = new Data[3, 3];
        map[1, 1] = new Data();
        map[1, 1].Text = "Test";
    }
}
```

Edit: fixed error.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] nine_labels = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" };

        var labelarray= new Label[3,3];

        // putting labels into matrix form

        int c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                var lbl = new Label();

                lbl.Text = nine_labels[c];

                lbl.Top = i * 100;
                lbl.Left = j * 100;

                labelarray[i, j] = lbl; 

                c++;
            }
        }

        // adding labels to form
        foreach (var item in labelarray)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(item);
        }

        // test

        labelarray[1, 1].Text = "test";
    }
```

NOTE: You'll need to add one button and call this function on `Click` of that button.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from tehMick actually lead to a runtime exception in .NET 2.0 but, except for that, the example is straight to the point.

The types of the two dimensional array must have a public accessible property, so you can access it directly as you said:

```
public class DTO
{
    private String myStrProperty;
    public String MyStrProperty
    {
        get {return myStrProperty; }
        set { myStrProperty = value; }
    }

    public DTO(string myStrProperty)
    {
        this.myStrProperty = myStrProperty;
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static Logger logger;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DTO[,] matrix = 
        {
            {new DTO("label1"), new DTO("label2")},
            {new DTO("label3"), new DTO("label4")}
        };

        matrix[0, 1].MyStrProperty = "otherValue";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that's specific to winforms.  Hopefully it will answer the question a little bit better:

```
    const int spacing = 50;
    Label[][] map = new Label[3][];
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        map[x] = new Label[3];
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            map[x][y] = new Label();
            map[x][y].AutoSize = true;
            map[x][y].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x * spacing, y * spacing);
            map[x][y].Name = "map" + x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString();
            map[x][y].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(spacing, spacing);
            map[x][y].TabIndex = 0;
            map[x][y].Text = x.ToString() + y.ToString();
        }
        this.Controls.AddRange(map[x]);
    }
    map[1][1].Text = "Test";
```

Comment: Works perfectly in Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.0 . How do I make this public accessible so I can use  map[XPOS][YPOS].Text = "Test"; everywhere in my code?

Comment: Just define the map at the appropriate scope.  It's probably best to make it a member of the form that contains the labels.  You can make it public as well, so that it can be accessed externally.

Comment: Brilliant Piece of code, +1

If I was to use this to navigate something around the map, using buttons such as Left, right etc..

Ik i'd code this by using something like if Left is pressed, the current position for X becomes -1

But my problem is I can't find a way to declare where I currently would be on the map, do you know a way how I can do this? Any help appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Update: Never mind, I've figured it out now, Thanks for the code you supplied though, helped a lot with what I'm trying to do!